# Lualatex (luaotfload) broke after upgrading to Mavericks

Tags: errors, luatex, fontspec, mac, luaotfload

Ever since I upgraded to OS X Mavericks—post hoc ergo propter hoc—I can no longer compile my dissertation using LuaLaTeX.

When running lualatex I first got the following error:

```
luaotfload | db: reload initiated; reason: “unresolved font name: ‘lucidacal
```

Segmentation fault: 11

'lucidacal' presumably refers to the Lucida Grande font, which I had installed in ~/Library/texmf. I removed ~/Library/texmf and ~/Library/texlive and now I get the following error:

```
luaotfload | db : Font names database not found, generating new one.
luaotfload | db : This can take several minutes; please be patient.Segmentation fault: 11
```

I can reproduce this error by running luaotfload-tool --update. At some point I also got the following error:

```
luaotfload | db: Font names database not found, generating new one.
Bus error: 10
```

I can't reproduce this, however.

I tried upgrading all packages using TeXLive but this didn't help.

I have no idea how to fix it and would be grateful for any clues!

Comment: Same trouble here. After upgrading to Mavericks my system crashes and can't typeset any lualatex file. My lualatex files contain gregorio font. The log message is: luaotfload | cache: No lookup cache, creating empty. luaotfload | db: Font names database not found, generating new one. Segmentation fault: 11 process crashed

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I tried the same and got `Segmentation fault: 11` too. So I retried with

```
luaotfload-tool -v -vvv -u
```

that shows all processing and saw it stopped when trying to load Skia.ttf.

So I edited

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-blacklist.cnf
```

(with `sudo`) and added `Skia.ttf` (the first two lines)

```
% Causes segmentation fault with Mavericks
Skia.ttf
% Takes ages to load
LastResort.ttf % a MacOSX font, but also available for free from unicode.org
% Segfaults under LuaTeX 0.76
lingoes.ttf
% http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2013-May/004239.html
Diablindall.ttf
spltfgbd.ttf
spltfgbi.ttf
spltfgit.ttf
spltfgrg.ttf
```

Rerunning `luaotfload -v -vvv -u` was successful.

Losing Skia is annoying, but not having a good font database is surely worse.

---

Note that also other fonts seem to be a cause for this. A user found that also `Silom.ttf` triggers a segmentation fault; running from the terminal

```
luaotfload-tool -v -vvv -u
```

will clearly show the culprit. The only known remedy is to add the offending font to the blacklist.

---

### News (2014-01-01)

The new version of `luaotfload` (2013/12/31, luaotfload v2.4) just uploaded for TeX Live, has `Skia.ttf` in the blacklist file.

```
% Takes ages to load
LastResort.ttf % a MacOSX font, but also available for free from unicode.org 
% Segfaults under LuaTeX 0.76
lingoes.ttf
% http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2013-May/004239.html
Diablindall.ttf
spltfgbd.ttf
spltfgbi.ttf
spltfgit.ttf
spltfgrg.ttf
% Buggy Max OS font, see https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/139
Skia.ttf
```

Comment: That seems to fix it, indeed! Somehow I missed the verbosity options in the man page. thx! I filed a bug here: https://github.com/khaledhosny/luaotfload/issues/55

Comment: @jdevuyst I was adding the reference to the “fix” and saw you did. Let's wait for an “official” fix. The font may have changed.

Comment: Skia.ttf uses AAT; support for AAT will be dropped from future versions of LuaTeX. See http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/dev-luatex/2013-October/004873.html

Comment: @MartinSchröder That's a pity, but I can understand and survive. `;-)`

Comment: Blacklisting the font as described doesn't work for me (OS X 10.9): luaotfload still hangs while trying to process the respective font as if nothing had changed. Also, the list of offending fonts is a long one for me: Nadeem.ttf, NISC18030.ttf, Osaka.ttf, OsakaMono.ttf, PCmyoungjo.ttf, Pilgiche.ttf, PlantagenetCherokee.ttf, Sathu.ttf and so on. I have to move these fonts from /Library/Fonts to /Library/Fonts Disabled. Does anyone have a clue why blacklisting doesn't work?

Comment: is there a fix for this yet? (by "fix" I mean something that is not just a bypass like egreg's otherwise fine answer)

Comment: @ClintEastwood I don't know if the maintainers of luaotfload have inserted Skia in the black list they distribute.

Comment: Same problem here, but blacklisting does not work. Since I'm a fresh Mac user I don't want to move the corresponding fonts as @TillA.Heilmann describes, because I don't know anything about side effects.

Comment: @typokurz I'll try experimenting, but till now I had no problem any more.

Comment: @egreg After updating my TL installation the problem disappeared.

Comment: Hi, egreg. It didn't works for me. I am on windows, using `ctex` documentclass, texlive. When I run `luaotfload-tool -v -vvv -u`, it didn't stop, it runs without problem. But tex compilation got errors. "(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu2lmr.fd)
luaotfload | db : Font names database not found, generating new one.
luaotfload | db : This can take several minutes; please be patient.

Error: Command crashed: lualatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "ctex-bug".tex"

Comment: @user15964 No output?

Comment: @egreg yes, no output