# TexLive installation unable to find system fonts in OSX Mavericks

Tags: fonts, xetex, mac

It seems my TeX system on OSX Mavericks is no longer able to find my system fonts. My tex documents no longer compile, and when I do:

```
$ xetex opentype-info.tex
```

I get:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/xetex/xetexfontinfo/opentype-info.texkpathsea:make_tex: Invalid fontname `Latin Modern Roman/ICU', contains ' '

! Font \testfont="Latin Modern Roman/ICU" at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) 
file or installed font not found.
l.26 \font\testfont="\myfontname/ICU" at 12pt
```

The fonts I'm trying to use ARE in my OSX system fonts. I think the problem is that LaTeX can't locate them.

In LaTex I have declarations like:

```
\setsansfont{ChunkFive}
```

and

```
\newfontfamily\mytitlefont[Color=signalflare]{ChunkFive}
```

This is resulting in errors.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Interesting. I can verify it.

Comment: If it's not in the system fonts, one has to specify the font by file name, like `\def\myfontname{[lmroman12-regular]}`

Comment: Actually, the fonts I'm trying to use ARE in my OSX system fonts. I think the problem is that LaTeX can't locate them. 

In LaTex I have declarations like:

    \\setsansfont{ChunkFive}

and 

\\newfontfamily\\mytitlefont[Color=signalflare]{ChunkFive}

This is resulting in errors.

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140840/lualatex-luaotfload-broke-after-upgrading-to-mavericks) question might be related to you problem.

Comment: Does this only happen with fonts that contain whitespace?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today after migrating my old user account to my new MacBook Pro. I had to purchase a cable (thanks to the new Thunderbolt I/O port) to connect the two machines together and in the intervening time I installed a fresh Tex installation from the MacTex package and verified the distribution was working with the latest version of TexShop (version 3.26).

With cable in hand (and $30 missing from my wallet) I ran Apple's Migration Assistant to transfer my old user account to the new machine. In the process it looks like Migration assistant broke the symbolic link to the texlive-2013 distribution.

In my case it *appears* migration assistant actually traversed the /usr/texbin link on my old machine and created a **directory** /usr/texbin in its place. Whether or not Migration Assistant was responsible, the problem is simple to fix.

```
mv /usr/texbin /usr/texbin.old
ln -s /Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin /usr/texbin
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".