# LuaLateX (luaotfload & blacklist) do not work in Mac OS X Mavericks (Segmentation error)

Tags: luatex, mac, luaotfload

I have the same problem as already stated by Till A. Heilmann under:
[Lualatex (luaotfload) broke after upgrading to Mavericks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140840/lualatex-luaotfload-broke-after-upgrading-to-mavericks)

After updating to Mavericks, LuaLaTeX does no longer work for me and when running

```
luaotfload-tool -v -vvv -u
```

I always get “Segmentation fault:” with and without editing

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-blacklist.cnf
```

So putting fonts on the blacklist has no affect.
After moving the font which didn't work into a different directory and rerunning

```
 luaotfload-tool -v -vvv -u
```

the error keeps occurring for a lot of other fonts (e.g. Krungthep.ttf, KufiStandardGK.ttf, Gungseouche.ttf, NISC18030.ttf and many more).
It seems to be a never ending story...
I would be very grateful for any suggestions how to handle this problem.

#### Update

Thanks for your reply.
However the

```
luaotfload-tool -b
```

command doesn't exist on my system - even after updating to the newest revision of luaotfload-tool via

```
tlmgr install luaotfload
```

as described in https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/blob/master/README.
Furthermore

```
luaotfload-tool --update --force --verbose=2
```

also didn't succed and it does not show a line of output for each processed font. So you do not know because of which font it stopped generating the database.
Nevertheless it now suddenly and somehow works, even with all the fonts which didn't work an hour ago, exept for Skia.ttf.
The only difference is that I closed my shell emulator and that I ran

```
 luaotfload-tool -fuvvv --log=stdout
```

as described in section 8.1 Troubleshooting (Database Generation) of the documentation of the luaotfload-package (ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/luatex/generic/luaotfload/luaotfload.pdf).
Sorry for asking such stupid questions.

Comment: 1) Please post the output of ``luaotfload-tool -b``; the font should be listed *with the exact name of the actual font file* which by default is ``Skia.ttf``.
The same goes for those other fonts you mention.
2) If the font is missing from the output, it means that Luaotfload can’t find the blacklist file. Symlink or copy it to the working directory and try again.
3) Fyi, ``luaotfload-tool -v -vvv`` is redundant and maybe ineffective. Use ``luaotfload-tool -vvuf`` (or ``luaotfload-tool --update --force --verbose=2`` to trace font files being read. I recommend you read ``man 1 luaotfload-tool``.

Comment: Btw. the current version of Luatex has the buggy AAT support removed; this entire class of problems will vanish with this year’s release of texlive.

Comment: those aren’t stupid questions.
If your luaotfload-tool lacks the ``-b`` (or ``--show-blacklist``) flag, this might indicate that there is something wrong with your installation.
Could you please post the output of ``luoatfload-tool --version``?
If it doesn’t print the version string ``2.4-3`` then the upgrade wasn’t successful.
(There should definitely be a ``-b`` flag and with ``--verbose=2`` the font names should be printed.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I suppose it didn't install properly.   
Now after running  `sudo tlmgr update --all`  version `2.4.3` is installed and the `-b` flag works as well as all font names are printed using `--verbose=2`.

Comment: Glad to hear another Luaotfload success story! ``=)``