# LuaTeX font database cannot be created in texlive (windows)

Tags: fonts, compiling, luaotfload

I'm trying to generate arabic article with a new package `arabluatex`, which requires  `lualatex` engine, writing simple "hello world" example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arabluatex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,RawFeature={+ss05}]{Amiri}
\begin{document}
hello world
\end{document}
```

And compile my test3.tex file with `lualatex`

```
lualatex test3.tex
```

Unfortunately the compilation do not succeed and  stagnate  for hours with this message

[image]

Note I have `texlive 2015` on windows 10

Comment: Probably there is some font it doesn't like. check http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140841/2388.

Comment: How  can I find the font which cause the problem?

Comment: Check the link.

Comment: Oh yes I run `luaotfload-tool -v -vvv -u` I find two font `cmunssdc.otf` and `mingliub.ttc` add the two file to `luaotfload-blacklist` and the problem is resolved  thanks @UlrikeFischer.

Comment: @salim bou: I doubt very much that ``cmunssdc.otf`` is broken in that respect as the CMU family has been tested with every version of Luaotfload for years. Perhaps you just keep a very buggy version of that font around? What  version is it?