# error: luaotfload | db : Font names database not found, generating new one

Tags: luatex, luaotfload

I'm using LuaLaTex on windows 8.1. While compiling encountered this error message:

```
 luaotfload | db : Font names database not found, generating new one.
 luaotfload | db : This can take several minutes; please be patient.
 Process crashed
```

Similar questions in this forum, as far as I know, where Linux/Mac specialized or have a differentiating character.

Comment: Normally this indicates a difficult font which should go in the blacklist: Call luaotfload-tool like this to find out the culprit: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140840/lualatex-luaotfload-broke-after-upgrading-to-mavericks/140841#140841

Comment: I called `luaotfload-tool -v -vvv -u`. It stopped at _lingoes.ttf_. After adding the font to the blacklist, it worked.

Comment: ``lingoes.ttf``? It was removed from the default blacklist after Luatex introduced lazy loading of font tables: https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/pull/195/commits/c3b803956524b0b5afb873a054556d0cdb89d063 -- but that was when the Fontforge libraries were still used. What version does Luatex report for you? Apart from shredding the buggy font, you might benefit from updating you TeX distro.